# Fetching image from database and directly read it into panel

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am fetching a image from database and directly read it into panel using Imageio.read method with Bufferimage reference variable but it gives me error **javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!** I don't understand why it gives me error.

My database code:

```
public class ValidateClass {

public static byte[] validateImageAndEmpId(Connection con, String empId) {
    byte[] imagedata = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select image from fingerprint where empId=?");
        ps.setString(1, empId);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image");
            imagedata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());

            System.out.println("Length" + imagedata);

            System.out.println("testlen" + imagedata.length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imagedata;
}
}
```

Code where I call this method:

```
      public CEntityForm() {

    jButtonStep1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jButtonStep3_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });

    /*jButtonStep1 for 1 to 1 match fingerprint matching which is not in use */
    jtool.add(jButtonStep1);

    try {
        // Taking picture1
        //Set picture new
        m_bimage1 = ImageIO.read(new File(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\L1Right.Jpeg"));
        m_panel1.setBufferedImage(m_bimage1);
        //Send image for skeletinization
        m_finger1.setFingerPrintImage(m_bimage1);
        finger1 = m_finger1.getFingerPrintTemplate();
        //See what skeletinized image looks like
        m_bimage1 = m_finger1.getFingerPrintImageDetail();
        m_panel1.setBufferedImage(m_bimage1);

        //fingerprint matching details of finger 1 in number format so commented jtextfield2
        // jTextField1.setText(m_finger1.ConvertFingerPrintTemplateDoubleToString(finger1));
        /*end of picture 1 details*/
        // Taking picture2
        //Set picture new
        Connection con = Conn.getConnection();

        byte[] bytearry = ValidateClass.validateImageAndEmpId(con, $emp_Id);
        // System.out.println("Input="+input);
        m_bimage2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearry));
        //   m_bimage2 = ImageIO.read(new File(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\L1Right_Copy.Jpeg"));
        m_panel2.setBufferedImage(m_bimage2);
        //Send image for skeletinization
        m_finger2.setFingerPrintImage(m_bimage2);
        finger2 = m_finger2.getFingerPrintTemplate();
        //See what skeletinized image looks like
        m_bimage2 = m_finger2.getFingerPrintImageDetail();
        m_panel2.setBufferedImage(m_bimage2);

        //fingerprint matching details of finger 2 in number format so commented jtextfield2
        //jTextField2.setText(m_finger2.ConvertFingerPrintTemplateDoubleToString(finger2));
        /*end of picture 1 details*/
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    this.getContentPane().add(m_panel1);
    this.getContentPane().add(m_panel2);
    this.getContentPane().add(jtool);

    this.setTitle("Entity");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
}
```

Main Method

```
      public class Testmain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
          new CEntityForm().setVisible(true);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
     javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
     at main.CEntityForm.<init>(CEntityForm.java:81)
     at main.Testmain.main(Testmain.java:18)
```

Comment: Looking at that stacktrace it seems like the `read(File)` variant is being called (that's the only one that can give that exception, and it's being called directly from your code), which seems impossible given the code you posted. Can you double-check that this is actually the code you run; maybe give us a more complete excerpt? What do the lines in `Testmain:18` and `CEntityForm:81` really look like?

Comment: testmain calss have method from there iam calling CEntityForm class

Comment: Yes. I'm really asking for the exact code around these areas (I don't know what you simplified / changed before posting it here). The way it is posted here, that exception should not happen. Especially the line in `CEntityForm`. Is it maybe possible you're running a different version of the code, maybe because of a failed compilation or similar?

Comment: ok will posted full code

Comment: I posted a full of code

Comment: on constructor i have written this code

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ANKURTIWARI I understand that you were asked to post your full code, but really, you shouldn't. Instead you should [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the Help Center. Note that this *includes any resources like the image you try to read*. Often this is a good tool to help you see your own problem. If not, it's **much** easier for other to help you if you do. PS: The exception indicates that the file exists, but isn't *readable* by your process/user (ie. a file access issue).

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to come from your other call to `ImageIO.read()`; the first one in the constructor. There you're passing a file that presumably doesn't exist.